# Replace blank and zero displayed prices by a text on WooCommerce product variations too

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I need to arguments. `$blank_price` and `$zero_price`. If the product price is left blank (not filled in), the product page will display the value of the `$blank_price` argument and if the product price is set to 0, the value from the `$zero_price` argument should be displayed.

I need this to work for both simple and variable products (variations).

Here is what I have so far, which works fine for simple products. I need help adding code for variable products.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_display', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_display( $price, $product ) {
    $blank_price = __('Price not yet set', 'woocommerce');
    $zero_price = __('Free', 'woocommerce');

    if( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        if ( '' === $product->get_price() ) {
            return $blank_price;
        } else if (0 == $product->get_price() ) {
            return $zero_price;
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work for Variations of a variable product as well, try this lightly changed code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'empty_and_zero_price_display', 20, 2 );
function empty_and_zero_price_display( $price, $product ) {
    $blank_price = __('Price not yet set', 'woocommerce');
    $zero_price = __('Free', 'woocommerce');

    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        if ( '' === $product->get_price() ) {
            return $blank_price;
        } else if (0 == $product->get_price() ) {
            return $zero_price;
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

> If you want to change the displayed **price range** on **Variable products**, that is something different, and you should give some more details related on how you want it to be displayed *(on all different cases combinations)*.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---